# Python - sockispy with mechanize (without monkeypatching)

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize, socks, tor

I want to know if there is a way to get mechanize.Browser to use a socks proxy (tor) without having to do this.

```
import socks, socket

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", port)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

My problem is that i have several threads that need to use socks proxies (tor instances) running on different ports. Now if i patch this socket module the way i did above all the threads end up using the same port which is not what i want.

So is there any way to do this without monkey patching?

I googled and found this http://blog.databigbang.com/distributed-scraping-with-multiple-tor-circuits/. But i don't know how to adapt this thing to mechanize.